# Getting the correct Date format in Apex Class or Trigger

Tags: apex

I have a Date field that I want to track the history of into a long text field, but I can't figure out how to get the correct date format (4/25/2015).

For example: for my Date field, if it equals 4/25/2015 and changes to 4/27/2015.

I want my Long text field to = 4/25/2015; 4/27/2015 and so on. How can I write this in a trigger or class?

I current have:

```
if (Trigger.isUpdate && new.Datefield != old.Datefield)
{
   new.longtextfield = new.datefield + ';' + old.longtextfield;
}
```

Which does not work. Could someone help me out?

Comment: Salesforce stores dates in GMT, which can sometimes be a problem. Do you need this to be in a particular time zone?

Comment: Why not just use field history tracking?

Comment: Not necessarily, I'm not too worried about the time. I just need the date. If I need a time zone then I can use Central (Chicago).

Comment: @AdrianLarson this date field changes often, so tracking the field could get messy.

Answer (score 2):

Salesforce date fields can be manipulated by the [DateTime class](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_datetime.htm#apex_System_Datetime_format_2). Try using one of the **"format"** methods provided to convert the date field into a string, in your local timezone and desired format, and then you can concatenated the dates.